# How to access to the google sheet the short cut ist pointing at?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have made a shortcut (new feature of google) of a google sheets.

Now I want to get all the Spreadsheets I have in a directory:
these function does not work anymore to treat all the Spreadsheet: `folder.getFilesByType(mimeType)` because the 'new' shortcut a new mime type has been introduced.
The ID of the shortcut is different from the original file. You can not access anymore over ID of the files you find in the directory.

1. What is the solution to select only spreadsheets and spreadsheets
   shortcuts in a directory?
2. How to open the spreadsheet a shortcut is pointing at?

```
    function myFunction() {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var idRepertoire=ss.getRange("A1").getValue();

      var monRep=DriveApp.getFolderById(idRepertoire);

      var fichiers=monRep.getFiles();


      while (fichiers.hasNext()) {
        var fichier=fichiers.next();
        var parentFichiers=fichier.getParents();
        while (parentFichiers.hasNext()){
          var parent=parentFichiers.next();
          var identiteF=fichier.getId();
          ss.appendRow([fichier.getName(),fichier.getMimeType(),identiteF,parent.getName()]);
          SpreadsheetApp.openById(identiteF).getSheetName("test").getRange("A1"); // causes an error for the shortcut
        }
      }

    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grcin.png
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for the shortcut your describing?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hello @Mikah, are you creating a new sheet using `sheet.new`? If that's the case, then the `MIME` type is the same as the one of a regular spreadsheet; same goes with the `id`. Would you mind providing more information about your issue here? Cheers!

Comment: @cooper https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support but it still uncomplete

Comment: @ale13 I have a folder containing sheets a script was reading the contents of all the sheets (which were partly present in different folders multiple parents) now the concept of multiple parents doesn't exist anymore. It is more like windows where you have a shortcut. This make it at my point of view impossible to access files with scripts as the neede shortcuts properties are not accessible

Comment: Hello @Mikah, I am not sure I understand - when you retrieve the Spreadsheet in the folder, the `MIME Type` is `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` still. Could please offer more details about this? Cheers!

Comment: Hello Ale13, I added this picture for more details https://i.stack.imgur.com/grcin.png
To repeat the same problem. Take a Spreadsheet drag and drop the sheet in another location while keeping CTRL pressed. This, in the past, has added a location for your file without changing the mime type. If you do the same action today it will create a new object type which is a shortcut (assuming that the rollout of the new feature already reached your region)

Comment: To my questions n°2 I am almost getting the solution. If I solve n°2 I will get the response for n°1

1st: turn on the advanced services of the GDRIVE-API (Class Files needed to access Metadata)
finally: You get access to the properties of Drive.Files:

"shortcutDetails": {
    "targetId": string,
    "targetMimeType": string }
I tried:
Drive.Files.get('shotcut_ID').shortcutDetails.targetId
returns
TypeError: Cannot read property 'targetId' of undefined (ligne 27, fichier "Code")

it seems that Drive.Files.get('shotcut_ID').shortcutDetails is not accessible.

Comment: Hey, have you tried creating the shortcut using the Drive API first? Or are you simply creating it by dragging and dropping the respective file?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your questions can be solved by using the **Drive API**.

#### Explanation

In order to retrieve **all the spreadsheets and the spreadsheet shortcuts**, you can use the `GET` request to retrieve the files:

- **For spreadsheet types:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

*With the following parameter for the* `q` *field*

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
```

- **For shortcut types:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files
```

*With the following parameter for the* `q` *field*

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut'
```

Afterwards, if you want to retrieve the files from the shortcuts above, you can simply do a `GET` request for each shortcut. So for one shortcut, you can do something like this, where `fileId` is in fact the **id of the shortcut**.

```
GET  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

*With the following parameters for the* `fields` *field*

```
shortcutDetails
```

After this `GET` request, you will receive a response in which you can find the `mimeType` of the shortcut as well as the original `id` of the file from the shortcut.

```
{
 "shortcutDetails": {
  "targetId": "ID_OF_THE_ORIGINAL_FILE",
  "targetMimeType": "MIME_TYPE_OF_THE_ORIGINAL_FILE"
 }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/);
- [Drive API Files:get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get);
- [Drive API Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/).