# How to create a shortcut in Google Drive Apps Script instead of multiple parents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, shortcut

I've been trying to read about it here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts

And I understand the basics in shortcuts but I can't figure out how to use it in the code - the syntax.

I need to instead of placing a folder in multiple folders, placing shortcuts in those folders named the same as the original folder.

I have an original folder called Project1 placed in Drafts. Shortcuts for this folder needs to be places in Folder2/Drafts, Folder3/Drafts and Folder4/Drafts.

If I afterwards change the name of the original folder Project1 ex. to "New Building" I need to find the shortcuts in Folder 2,3 and 4 (by Id? - I can put the ID of the shortcuts in a datasheet from where I can iterate through them) - and then rename them as the original folder's new name.

And when I move the Project1 from Drafts to Confirmed. I need to move the shortcuts from Folder2/Drafts to Folder2/Confirmed etc.

This is mainly how the basic code looked like for placing the new folder

```
        var folder1 = draft.createFolder("DRAFT - "+"Project1");
        var folder1Url = folder1.getUrl();
        var folder1Id = folder1.getId();
        folder2Draft.addFolder(folder1);
```

When changing the name of the folder the name would (of course) change in the other places. But as I understand this is not the case with shortcuts. I've tested it with manually created shortcuts witch confirmed this.

The renaming part I do like this when confirming the project:

```
   var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder1Id);
   var folder1NameOld = folder1.getName();
   var folder1NameNew = folder1NameOld.replace("DRAFT - ","");
   folder1.setName(folder1NameNew);
```

And I move the file when confirming the project with the simple:

```
    confirmed.addFolder(folder1);
    draftsFolder.removeFolder(folder1);
```

The script is made in a spreadsheet and I already put alle the folderIDs in a data sheet in the file so I can very easy make references to the different folders and if needed also collect the IDs of the shortcuts to be able to rename them.

Update:
To make a more clear question:
How to do this with shortcuts instead of multi-parenting?

```
function shortcut() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = s.getActiveSheet();
  var projectFolderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var folder1DraftId = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var folder2DraftId = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();

  var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(projectFolderId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folder1DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folder2DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610327/7215091) answer your question?

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the reply. Maybe it actually do answer my question. But then I'm just not able to understand it ;-) I've updated my post above with a simple and clear question (I hope) to break it down to the very minimal. From there I think I will be able to do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following script as the shortcut.

  ```
  function shortcut() {

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = s.getActiveSheet();
    var projectFolderId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
    var folder1DraftId = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
    var folder2DraftId = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();

    var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(projectFolderId);
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folder1DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folder2DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
  }
  ```
- At above script, `folder1` is put in the folders of `folder1DraftId` and `folder2DraftId`.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the method of files.create in Drive API is used. But in the current stage, the method of Files: insert in Drive API v2 can also create the shortcut. So in this answer, Drive API v2 of Advanced Google services is used.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

From:

```
var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(projectFolderId);
DriveApp.getFolderById(folder1DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
DriveApp.getFolderById(folder2DraftId).addFolder(folder1);
```

To:

```
const folderIDs = [folder1DraftId, folder2DraftId];
folderIDs.forEach(f => {
  Drive.Files.insert({
    shortcutDetails: {targetId: projectFolderId},
    parents: [{id: f}],
    title: DriveApp.getFolderById(projectFolderId).getName(),
    mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut"
  });
});
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Create a shortcut to a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)
- [Files: insert of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)

  - The official document says as follows.

    - > Note: Apps creating shortcuts with `files.insert` must specify the MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`.
    - But, when `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` is used, the shortcut couldn't be created. I'm not sure whether this is the bug or the current specification. So I used `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut` as the mimeType.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to proceed. Thank you!

Comment: @Kasper Egelund Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: In the current stage, your goal can be achieved using Drive service (DriveApp) as follows. `const folderIDs = [folder1DraftId, folder2DraftId]; folderIDs.forEach(f => DriveApp.createShortcut(projectFolderId).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(f)));`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createshortcuttargetid)