# How to add file to My Drive using Drive API v3?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, urlfetch

The Google Drive API v3 recently changed so that files can only exist in one folder. This broke the Apps Script tool I use to load folders into each domain user's My Drive (with the folder Id 'root').

What is the new way to add a folder to My Drive?

```js
var service = getService(userEmail);

var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + driveId +'?addParents=' + parentId;
Logger.log(url);

var options = {
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method'     : 'patch',
  'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
  //https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

var found = response.getResponseCode()
if (found == 200) { found = 'Added to My Drive' } else {
  Logger.log('Failed with response code: %s', found);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google Drive's new shortcut MIME type! You can reference Google's example [Create a shortcut to a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts#node.js) for hints. Keep in mind that Advanced Drive Services is limited to Drive API v2, but URLFetchApp can also use Drive API v3.

The code below is for URLFetchApp. If you would rather use Advanced Drive Service, see this answer instead: [How to create a shortcut in Google Drive Apps Script instead of multiple parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047554/how-to-create-a-shortcut-in-google-drive-apps-script-instead-of-multiple-parents)

```js
/*
 * Create a new shortcut using UrlFetchApp.
 *
 * @param {String} driveId    Id of the file/folder to use as a shortcut target.
 * @param {String} userEmail  User email address for change context and OAuth token.
 * @param {String} parentId   The parent folder for the shortcut file.
 * @param {String} driveName  The display name of the shortcut.
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts
 * https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create
 * https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2
 */
function TEST_addShortcut() { addShortcut('DriveKey0123456789ABCDEabcde',
                                          'Username@CompanyDomain.com',
                                          'root',
                                          'The file or folder name')
};

function addShortcut(driveId, userEmail, parentId, driveName) {
  var service = getService(userEmail); //apps-script-oauth2 library
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log("addShortcut hasAccess, User %s",userEmail);
    
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/';
    var data = {
      'shortcutDetails': {'targetId': driveId},
      'name'       : driveName,
      'mimeType'   : 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut',
      'parents'    : parentId //Use Id 'root' for user's My Drive folder
    };
    var options = {
      'method'     : 'POST',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
      'payload'    : JSON.stringify(data) // Convert JavaScript object to JSON string
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var resultStringy = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
    var respCode = response.getResponseCode()
    Logger.log('addShortcut code %s, result: %s', respCode, resultStringy);
    return (respCode == 200);
    
  } else {
    
    Logger.log('addShortcut getLastError: %s', service.getLastError());
    Logger.log('addShortcut(%s) = %s',userEmail,'No Access');
    return null; //Service does not have access
  }
};
```