# Create "Open With..." External Link in Google Drive with App Script

Tags: web, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create an external link in Google Drive (mime type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`) through the App Script of my Add-on. The end to end goal is to create this file, send the id to an external service (my service) and that way, when my users clicks the "Open with..." on this file in Google Drive, it will send them to my service along with the `state` param (which contains the `fileId`) and I can Do The Right Thing (TM) with it.

For some reason, I can't seem to get the `DriveApp` API in App Script to do this. The code for this is:

```
const file = DriveApp.createFile('DriveAppFile', '', 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk');
```

The `createFile` calls fails with `Error Exception: Invalid argument`. From what I gather, it's the `mimeType` parameter that the interpreter doesn't like. I am explicitly setting the contents to empty string because this is required for a file of type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` as per Google's docs. I have also tried `null` for the contents but to no avail. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

One other piece of information: out of curiosity, I tried to perform this same action from a test nodeJS app using the `googleapis:v3` and surprisingly, everything works fine. While it does work, this is not a good option for my users because I don't want to have them OAuth connect from my external app to Google just to perform this one action when they have already OAuth'ed via my Add-on.

Comment: If you want to create a file with the filename of `DriveAppFile` and the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`, you can achieve this usind Drive API like `Drive.Files.insert({title: "DriveAppFile", mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk"})`. Before you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. But I'm not sure whether this is the answer for your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: So as far as I can tell, `Drive.Files.insert` is deprecated. It seems as though we now have to use `DriveApp.createFile` which doesn't have a function signature that takes a JS object. As for what I'm trying to achieve, please see my post for a brief answer to the end-to-end goal. Thanks for the help so far and your English is great!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `So as far as I can tell, Drive.Files.insert is deprecated.`, I cannot understand it. Can you provide the detail information about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mimeTypes` document you have shared is in fact related to the `Drive API`, which is different from `DriveApp`.

If you want to make use of the `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk` mime type, I suggest you use it in the way it was mentioned in the comments

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: "DriveAppFile", mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk"})
```

In order to enable the **Advanced Drive Service**, you will have to go to *Services* > *Add service...*

[image: add drive service]

#### Notes

- It's important to bear in mind that the Drive Advanced Service makes use of the Drive API v2.
- If you want to use `DriveApp`, the supported mime types are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type).

#### References

- [Drive API v2 files:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert);
- [Apps Script Enum Type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type);
- [How to create a shortcut in Google Drive Apps Script instead of multiple parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047554/how-to-create-a-shortcut-in-google-drive-apps-script-instead-of-multiple-parents).

Comment: Bingo! Thanks ale13 and @Tanaike.