# Google Drive Automation: Automatically generate a shortcut to an image file within a folder upon renaming the image file to match the folder's name

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula

I'm completely new to Google Apps Script and eager to enhance my skills in automating tasks on Google Drive. I'm wondering if it's feasible to automatically create a shortcut to an image file within a folder when the image file is renamed to match the folder's name. I have numerous folders in my Google Drive, each containing multiple files. The goal is that when I rename an image file, a shortcut to it should be generated in the corresponding folder based on name matching between the image file and the folder. Is this achievable?

I've attempted to accomplish this through Google Sheets, but it's quite time-consuming to gather all the file names and folder names into the sheet, and then analyze which file names are not in the list. If an image file name isn't in the list, then it selects that file and matches its name with the folder name to create a shortcut in the folder.

Comment: Having read the question, I’m not clear about exactly what is the problem that you are trying to solve, what parts of the process you have completed and what remains to be done. I'm also unclear about your expectations for the question since StackOverflow is not a free, code-writing service. Would you please clarify “what exactly is the task(s) that you want to do”, and what have you done to resolve the problem. You might also include some sample data and examples of successful outcomes.

Comment: Related question:[How to create a shortcut in Google drive apps script instead of multiple parents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053779/1330560). This contains a good answer, some helpful comments, and a link to a further useful related question.